# How do I change my Interfaces to up instead of down status?

Tags: router, serial, protocol

What command do I use to change a S0/0/0 interface with PPP Encapsulation from a line protocol of down to up? I have already applied a no shutdown command.

Comment: You need to make sure the speed, duplex, and clock rate settings are same at both ends before the line protocol is up. That's your first basics.

Comment: Cock rate is show with the `show controllers` command.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your talking about a CISCO device, since you've already issued the `no shutdown` command the line should automatically come up when it starts communicating with something at the other end. Verify that the config is proper on both connections. 
If you want to see what you've already done, try doing a `show running-config` to see what the current config is on that interface and fix and mis-configurations.

If you it's not obvious, start working your way through the OSI layers to troubleshoot the problem.